# Centos6.3 PHP5.3 can not run php script at background

Tags: php

Today, a strange problem occur when I test my code.
In my company server, is Centos 6.3 and PHP 5.3, when I run php script with simple &, it can not work, but if I run this script direct or with nohup, it work good.

This is what I try with the problem.

My php test script

```
<?php 
echo 'Hello World!';
```

When I use this command to run it work good

```
[root@sjc ~]# /usr/bin/php test.php
Hello World!
```

And it work good with nohup too

```
[root@sjc ~]# nohup /usr/bin/php test.php >> res 2>&1 &
[1] 14658
[root@sjc ~]# cat res
nohup: ignoring input
Hello World!
[1]+  Done                    nohup /usr/bin/php test.php >> res 2>&1
```

But when I run this script at background without nohup, it can not work

```
[root@sjc ~]# /usr/bin/php test.php &
[1] 14685
[root@sjc ~]#
```

Only when I put it back, it continue work

```
[root@sjc ~]# fg
/usr/bin/php test.php
Hello World!
[root@sjc ~]#
```

It's Strange!!!

Comment: I think there was a bug in CentOS, where the ouput buffers and after something like 2MB of output it crashes the buffer.  I had a similar issue but it was CentOS5 and had to use `>/dev/null 2>&1` with all my cron jobs.  Not sure if it's the same issue. But if you output a lot it could be.  When you run in the shell it has somewhere to send output to, when you run in background it just buffers it tell it crashes.

Comment: Basically what happened to me is it stored all the output in memory because there was no shell and no file to send it to. Once the memory limit for the buffer is hit it just craps out.  So by sending the output to null, it just flushes it down the drain and never hits the limit.  You can test it by running it with something like this `/usr/bin/php test.php >/dev/null 2>&1 &`